# Deserializing JSON into Object with list attribute

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have two objects, Product with OneToMany self reference and OneToMany relationship to Image.

From a Rest API, I need to create CRUD services. I created the following services:

Add new Product:
{"name":"chair",
"description":"red chair"}

```
@Path("/product/add")
@Consumes("application/json")
```

Add new Child Product:
{"name":"table",
"description":"red table"}

```
@Path("/product/{id}/addChild")
@Consumes("application/json")
```

Add Image to Product:

/product/1/image/add

{"type":"PNG"}

```
@Path("/product/{id}/image/add")
@Consumes("application/json")
```

Update Product:

/product/update/1

{"name":"chair",
"description":"blue chair"}

```
@Path("/product/update/{id}")
@Consumes("application/json")
```

Update Image:

/image/update/1

{"type":"JPEG"}

```
@Path("/image/update/{id}")
@Consumes("application/json")
```

Delete Product:

/product/delete/1

```
@DELETE
@Path("/product/delete/{id}")
```

Delete Image:

/image/delete/1

```
@DELETE
@Path("/image/delete/{id}")
```

Product.java:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer productId;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
private List<Image> images;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
private List<Product> children;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PRODUCT_ID")
private Product parent;
```

Image.java:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Image implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer imageId;

@Column(name = "TYPE")
private String type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
private Product product;
```

When I try to add a Product with a Image, I got an error:

{"name":"bucket",
"description":"red bucket",
"images":{"type":"jpeg"}
}

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@3c9786ad; line: 2, column: 27] (through reference chain: br.com.model.Product["images"])

Need help to:

1. Add with one JSON a Product with Images;
2. The way of adding child products is correct (using PathParam)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `images` property in json string is not an array/list, it is an object. It should also be encapsulated with `[]` to be so, not only with `{}`. That's why the deserialization fails.

Comment: you mean like this: {"name":"bucket", "description":"red bucket", "images":["type":"jpeg"] }

Comment: no, like this: {"name":"bucket", "description":"red bucket", "images":[{"type":"jpeg"}] }

Comment: Try it but no sucess, this is what was printed at jetty log:              
Product [id=null, name=bucket, description=red bucket, parent=null, children=null]
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        Product
        (DESCRIPTION, NAME, PARENT_PRODUCT_ID)
    values
        (?, ?, ?)

Comment: @PedroGrandi now it seems we solved the json deserialization problem, which was stated in the title. So you should accept this answer :)